# Oracle: how to compare multiple rows in sql developer and make sure they are the same?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following table as follows:

```
League_id     League_name          Team_id     Team_name
257           Copa America         11111       ABC
122           Brazil A             11111       ABC
135           La Liga              987         FC Barca
129           Copa Del Rey         987         *FC Barca Football
```

`*Notice that there each team could play in different leagues`

I would like to put a sanity check on `Team_name` Column, and make sure that the `Team_name` is the SAME throughout all leagues. i.e. `FC Barca Football` should be flagged because it is not the same as `FC Barca` in a different league.

What is the best way to approach this check?

an error message as follows should produce: 
 "Team_Name discrepancy for Team_ID = 987" for leagues: La Liga (135) and Copa Del Rey (129)

Thank you,

Answer (score 4):

The appropriate way to approach this is to not store the `team_name` in this table.  The `team_name` column belongs in the `team` table (where, I assume, the `team_id` is the primary key).  Realistically, the `league_name` also shouldn't be in this table either-- it should be in the `league` table where `league_id` is the primary key.

So you really need three tables

```
CREATE TABLE league( 
  league_id   NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  league_name VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE team(
  team_id   NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  team_name VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE team_league(
  team_league_id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  team_id        NUMBER REFERENCES team( team_id ),
  league_id      NUMBER REFERENCES league( league_id ),
  CONSTRAINT uk_team_league UNIQUE( team_id, league_id )
);
```

You could then create a view that produces the data you have presented here

```
SELECT l.league_id, l.league_name,
       t.team_id,   t.team_name
  FROM league l
       JOIN team_league tl on (l.league_id = tl.league_id)
       JOIN team t on (tl.team_id = t.team_id)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Justin. I already have those tables; that was how I got the example table in the first place. my question is to how to compare those columns after the fact that I joined my tables together? thanks again

Comment: @user1683987 - If you have the three tables I mentioned, you would never create the table you posted.  Creating the denormalized table introduces the potential for data to get out of sync.  The table you posted should not exist.  You may want a view that presents the data.  Since a view is just a stored query and the underlying data is normalized, there is no way for the view to return a different `team_name` for the same `team_id`.

Comment: I understand, and that makes sense. this is just a sanity check to see if any different `team_name` returns. I doesn't have to if everything is in order... sometimes people mess with the database manually and that is why I'd like to do this check.

Comment: @user1683987 - There is no possible way to manually (or otherwise) manipulate the data in the database such that the query I posted will ever return the same `team_id` with a different `team_name`.  When the data is properly normalized, the benefit is that every piece of information is stored in exactly one place so it is impossible to have conflicting information.

Comment: like I said, this is just a sanity check. It does not have to return anything, this is just to make sure we catch anybody that changes `team_name`, which is not primary offcourse, and it is possible for that happen

Comment: this will eventually go into a procedure which will run everyday to catch this name discrepancy. It will produce an error message such as: "Team_Name discrepancy for Team_ID = 987" for leagues: La Liga (135) and Copa Del Rey (129)

Comment: @user1683987 - There is no reason to check this ever if your data model is correct.  It is impossible for the query I posted with the data model I posted to ever have a case where there is a discrepancy.  It doesn't matter what data the users insert, how the data is inserted, or anything else.  It is simply impossible for there to be a conflict.  Just like you wouldn't run a job to check to see whether the primary key has duplicates or NULL values or a foreign key has allowed orphaned rows, it makes no sense to check this.

Comment: well, I have to disagree with you on that...I just edited the team_name and the query came back as that, which makes sense since 'team_name' is not primary.

Comment: If you updated the `team_name` in the `team` table, all the rows in the query for that `team_id` will have the new `team_name`.  The only way you can get a conflict is if you materialize the table that you posted in your question.  You should not materialize that table-- it should simply be a view.

Comment: what you say makes sense according to the above table. my `Team Table` however consists of `team_id`, `team_name`, `league_id` and my `League Table` has `league_id` and `league_name`. these are the tables i have and i cannot change them.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a separate table (Teams) with team_id and team name.  Put a unique constraint on those.  Then put the League table with League_id, League_name, Team_id.
So when you do the query you pull the team_name from the teams table reducing the redundancy of allowing multiple team names per team_id.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to normalise your tables.

In other words:

Create a TEAM table with an *id* and a *team name* column.
Create a LEAGUE table with an *id* and a *league name* column.

A league can contain **many** teams and a team can contain **many** leagues.
This should therefore be modelled as a **many to many** relationship.

i.e.
create a TEAM_LEAGUE table with a *league id* and a *team id* field

This modelling avoids the problem because there is now one unique team name for the given team.

Comment: thanks. tables are normalized and I had to join them to get the above product. Now the question is how to put in the sanity check